# Which JS framework is best fit for drag and drop, resize and rotate functionality..?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, rotation, resize

I am going to do a web app with images and text with user handle functionalities like drag-drop,resize and rotate.

I already used Jquery UI js to achieve **drag-drop, rotate and resize,** but its not seems to be a good one to achieve all those things without problems. One of the problem is, in rotation i can't able to create four corner handles to rotate image and for resize i face problem and used another js link(resizable-rotation.patch.js).

Please prescribe me which Js is best to achieve all those things(drag - drop, resize and rotate).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this question is *too broad* so

I think you might want to take a look at the [documentation](http://interactjs.io/docs/#) of

- *[Interact.js](http://interactjs.io/)*  which is good for all *drag drop rotate and resize*
- For drag drop and resize there is another -  [konvajs](http://konvajs.github.io/docs/sandbox/Image_Resize.html) and the [documentation](https://github.com/konvajs/konva)
- For importing the vector graphics too ,here is another great library [fabricjs](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js)

Demo can be shown [here](http://fabricjs.com/demos/)

Comment: @ pritishvaidya.. Is it rotate image functionality existing in **interact.js** and **konvasjs**..?  I already visited those two js. But **fabricjs** is new to me.. 
Please prescribe some more js..

Comment: rotate functionality is there in interact js but not in konvajs,and you can also try looking into this https://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Utils/Draggable/ ,by setting the `onClick` and `onDrag` function to the same,similar functionalities can be achieved

Comment: Can you send the link of working interact.js rotate functionality using handles..?

Comment: In InteractJs rotate + resize is not possible for at least now. you can see here this issue is still open : https://github.com/taye/interact.js/issues/569